# In wildfly 19, Why am I getting javax.faces.FacesException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: a minimum and / or a maximum have to be specified?

Tags: jsp, jsf, jboss, wildfly, myfaces

I am migrating a really old application from jboss 6 to wildfly 19. It bases on EJB2 and JSF1.2 - MyFaces. Application is deployed, but when I try to reach one of JSP page (wrapped with JSF) then I am getting an error, which tells me nothing. Is there somebody who could know what does it mean? Thanks in advance for help.

```
[javax.faces.webapp._ErrorPageWriter] (default task-1) An exception occurred: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: a minimum and / or a maximum have to be specified
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:347)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.buildView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:486)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:337)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:140)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:187)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:122)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:374)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at myoldapplication.package.web.filter.ExtranetFilter.doFilter(ExtranetFilter.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at myoldapplication.package.web.filter.PerformanceFilter.doFilter(PerformanceFilter.java:33)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at myoldapplication.package.web.filter.ForceCharacterEncodingAndContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ForceCharacterEncodingAndContentTypeFilter.java:69)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at myoldapplication.package.web.filter.ChineseWallsFilter.doFilter(ChineseWallsFilter.java:33)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: a minimum and / or a maximum have to be specified
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:889)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:818)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspService(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:316)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:251)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:227)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:149)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:341)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: a minimum and / or a maximum have to be specified
    at org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.GenericMinMaxValidatorTag.createValidator(GenericMinMaxValidatorTag.java:70)
    at org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ValidateLongRangeTag.createValidator(ValidateLongRangeTag.java:43)
    at javax.faces.webapp.ValidatorELTag.doStartTag(ValidatorELTag.java:50)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fvalidateLongRange_005f0(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:3794)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005finputText_005f0(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:3760)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fpanelGrid_005f0(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:3610)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fform_005f2(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:3545)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_t_005fdocumentBody_005f1(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:777)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_t_005fhtmlTag_005f1(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:693)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:359)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspService(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:301)
    ... 97 more
```

Comment: This stack trace appears incomplete. Check server logs for full stack trace. The answer is usually in bottommost root cause.

Comment: @BalusC, Thank you for your advice and fixes in title. I have edited my post and uploaded full stack trace of my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting a stack trace, always look at the bottommost root cause. The answer is usually right there.

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: a minimum and / or a maximum have to be specified
    at org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.GenericMinMaxValidatorTag.createValidator(GenericMinMaxValidatorTag.java:70)
    at org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ValidateLongRangeTag.createValidator(ValidateLongRangeTag.java:43)
    at javax.faces.webapp.ValidatorELTag.doStartTag(ValidatorELTag.java:50)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fvalidateLongRange_005f0(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:3794)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005finputText_005f0(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:3760)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fpanelGrid_005f0(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:3610)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fform_005f2(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:3545)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_t_005fdocumentBody_005f1(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:777)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_t_005fhtmlTag_005f1(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:693)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:359)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.order.BiorderFilter_jsp._jspService(BiorderFilter_jsp.java:301)
    ... 97 more
```

Carefully read out aloud the class/method names from bottom to top until some parts become sensible:

- `BiorderFilter.jsp` file is being serviced
- `<f:view>` tag
- `<t:html>` tag
- `<t:documentBody>` tag
- `<h:form>` tag
- `<h:panelGrid>` tag
- `<h:inputText>` tag
- `<f:validateLongRange>` tag
- start of tag
- create validator of type `ValidateLongRangeTag`
- create validator of type `GenericMinMaxValidatorTag`
- problem: "a minimum and / or a maximum have to be specified"

So most likely you have a `BiorderFilter.jsp` file with a `<f:validateLongRange>` tag which doesn't have a `minimum` and / or a `maximum` attribute specified.

```
<h:inputText ...>
   <f:validateLongRange />
</h:inputText>
```

Just specify at least one of those attribues with a non-`null` value and this problem shall disappear. E.g.:

```
<h:inputText ...>
   <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" />
</h:inputText>
```

Or probably the whole validator is unnecessary for the specific input, you'd best just remove it. It's known that some developers use this way in order to ensure that the inputted value is a `Long` instead of e.g. `Double`. But for that a `Converter` should be used instead of a `Validator`, or simply a strictly typed `<h:inputText value="#{bean.value}">` where `value` is of type `Long` so that JSF does the automatic conversion by itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for help and explanation. Know I can see the analogy between errorlog and the structure of my JSP page. You are awesome! Best regards.